# how do I get the latest messages from Telegram API?

Tags: json, telegram

(First, I want to note that this didn't answer my question: [How to get the latest/new messages from Telegram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178748/how-to-get-the-latest-new-messages-from-telegram-api))

I am building a history object to poll the 20 latest messages from a channel/chat:

```
get_history = GetHistoryRequest(
        peer=input_peer,
        offset_id=0,
        offset_date=None,
        add_offset=0,
        limit=20,
        max_id=0,
        min_id=0,
        hash=0
    )
```

The API here:

https://core.telegram.org/api/offsets

mentions max_date and min_date.

I imagine to get the latest messages, I should use limit=[number], offset_date=[same_number] and max_date be the date at the moment. However, I can't get from the API documentation how "max_date" should be represented. Any ideas how, and whether I am correct in my assumptions in getting the latest 20 messages?

This is also useful to have around: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory